# Trying to write a stored procedure where I can send the columns as dynamic instead of hard coded during search

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a stored procedure which is where I am trying to figure out how to use the use searching of the columns, I can't hardcode the columns because I am using all columns in the frontend, I want to this as dynamic list.

Here is the stored procedure I am trying to create:

```
CREATE OR ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[Assignments]
    @SEARCH_TEXT AS VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @SORT_COLUMN_NAME AS VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @SORT_COLUMN_DIRECTION AS VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @START_INDEX AS INT = 0,
    @PAGE_SIZE AS INT = 10,
    @assignmentID INT = NULL -- this might pass or might not pass, I   mean it can be empty 
    -- I can add more variables here like differentiate for dates, 
    -- numeric and varchar columns in this as a list, just need to know 
    -- how can I use in the stored procedure
AS
BEGIN
    -- The number of rows affected by the different commands
    -- does not interest the application, so turn NOCOUNT ON
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @QUERY AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
            @ORDER_QUERY AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
            @CONDITIONS AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
            @PAGINATION AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SET @QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE ' + @assignmentID + 
                 ' IS NULL OR assignmentID =' + @assignmentID

    -- SEARCH OPERATION
    IF (ISNULL(@SEARCH_TEXT, '') <> '')
    BEGIN
        IF (ISDATE(@SEARCH_TEXT) = 1) 
           SET @CONDITIONS = ' WHERE CAST(date_of_birth AS DATE) = CAST('+@SEARCH_TEXT+'AS DATE)'
        ELSE IF (ISNUMERIC(@SEARCH_TEXT) = 1)
        BEGIN
            SET @CONDITIONS = ' WHERE salary = ' + @SEARCH_TEXT + 
                              ' OR phone_number = CAST(' + @SEARCH_TEXT + 'AS VARCHAR(50))'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @CONDITIONS = ' WHERE first_name LIKE ''%' + @SEARCH_TEXT + '%''
      OR first_name +'' ''+last_name LIKE ''%'+@SEARCH_TEXT+'%''
      OR last_name LIKE ''%'+@SEARCH_TEXT+'%''
      OR email LIKE ''%'+@SEARCH_TEXT+'%''
      OR gender LIKE ''%'+@SEARCH_TEXT+'%''
      OR department LIKE ''%'+@SEARCH_TEXT+'%''
      OR phone_number LIKE ''%'+@SEARCH_TEXT+'%'' '
    END
END
```

Comment: What is an "SPX"?

Comment: well its a stored procedure but short name as SPX

Comment: But why the "X"? SP for Stored Procedure, sure, but why an SPX? What does the X mean? I thought you might mean an E**x**tended **S**tored **P**rocedure, but that isn't what the above is, hence my question of what you mean by "SPX".

Comment: As a separate note, you are creating a large injection issue in the above. If you want to use dynamic SQL you should still *parametrise* your **parameters**; *never* inject them.

Comment: ok, we discussed this but can guidance be provided how can i handlke it

Answer (score 2):

This type of query is called a Kitchen Sink Query, and is best done by using dynamic SQL, but verifying that all columns are valid and escaped correctly.

- You can pass in a comma-separated list of columns to search, and then comapre that against `sys.columns` or a whitelist.
- Dynamic SQL should be in `nvarchar(max)`.
- Object and column names go in `sysname`.
- You must parameterize everything that can be parameterized, everything else must be checked against a whitelist or a system view.
- You can pass parameters through to `sp_executesql`, see below.
- Datetimes should not be cast to `date`, instead use a date range.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Assignments
    @SEARCH_TEXT AS varchar(50) = '',
    @SEARCH_COLUMN_NAMES nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @SORT_COLUMN_NAMES AS sysname = NULL,
    @SORT_COLUMN_DIRECTION AS varchar(4) = 'ASC',
    @START_INDEX AS INT = 0,
    @PAGE_SIZE AS INT = 10,
    @assignmentID INT = NULL
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @QUERY AS nvarchar(max),
        @CONDITIONS AS nvarchar(max);

SET @QUERY = '
SELECT e.*
FROM Employees e
';

IF @assignmentID IS NOT NULL
    SET @CONDITIONS = 'assignmentID = @assignmentID';

IF ISNULL(@SEARCH_TEXT, '') <> ''
    SET @CONDITIONS = ISNULL(@CONDITIONS + '
  OR ', '') +
      CASE WHEN ISDATE(@SEARCH_TEXT) = 1
      THEN
        'date_of_birth >= @startDate AND date_of_birth < @endDate'
           WHEN TRY_CAST(@SEARCH_TEXT AS int) IS NOT NULL
      THEN
        'salary = @searchNumber
  OR phone_number = @SEARCH_TEXT'
      ELSE
        ISNULL((
          SELECT STRING_AGG(
            QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' LIKE @SEARCH_TEXT',
            '
  OR'
          )
          FROM STRING_SPLIT(@SEARCH_COLUMN_NAMES, ',') s
          JOIN sys.columns c ON c.name = TRIM(s.value)
          WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Employees')
        ), '1=0') + '
  OR first_name + '' '' + last_name LIKE @SEARCH_TEXT'
      END;

SET @QUERY += ISNULL('
WHERE ' + @CONDITIONS, '');

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Employees')
      AND c.name = @SORT_COLUMN_NAME
)
    SET @QUERY += '
ORDER BY ' + QUOTENAME(@SORT_COLUMN_NAME) + IIF(@SORT_COLUMN_DIRECTION = 'DESC', 'DESC', 'ASC') + '
OFFSET @START_INDEX ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PAGE_SIZE ROWS ONLY;
';

PRINT @QUERY;   -- your friend


DECLARE @searchNumber int = TRY_CAST(@SEARCH_TEXT AS int),
        @startDate datetime = TRY_CAST(@SEARCH_TEXT AS datetime);
DECLARE @endDate datetime = DATEADD(day, 1, @startDate);

EXEC sp_executesql
  @QUERY,
  N'@SEARCH_TEXT varchar(50),
    @START_INDEX int,
    @PAGE_SIZE int,
    @assignmentID int,
    @searchNumber int,
    @startDate datetime,
    @endDate datetime',

    @SEARCH_TEXT = @SEARCH_TEXT,
    @START_INDEX = @START_INDEX,
    @PAGE_SIZE = @PAGE_SIZE,
    @assignmentID = @assignmentID,
    @startDate = @startDate,
    @endDate = @endDate;
```

Comment: Thakns, but my question was to pass the column in the stored procedure as a list so i do not have to dynamically fetch thier names or as you mentioned in sysname, that i really do not how to, please guide on that

Comment: i still find this quite confusing, can we modify your answer to have the columns for search passed in the create proc as a list, because i will get from there and then create that code which will handle the search

Comment: @cf-uuser you could do that but it would mean that you have to first parse your delimited list and then verify that every column passed in is a valid column. Anything less means you are vulnerable to sql injection which is sadly still the #1 attack vector.

Comment: @cf-uuser Yes of course, see edits. Note how the values are compared to `sys.columns` and `QUOTENAME` is used to correctly quote

Comment: @chalieface why you are still using first_name or last_name or dateofbirth

Comment: if they are to be dynamic, they have to be dynamic

Comment: Because those appeared to have specific handling: `date_of_birth` needed conversion to `datetime` and it seemed you wanted to check separately for a combination of `first_name last_name`. You can modify as needed, just follow the logic.